# Initializing and setting events inside a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how can I set the test function for the keyup element inside the test() function;
What would be only the function call in document ready, and all other events in the function itself.

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  test: function() {
    $(this).val("123");
  }
  $(this).test();
  $(this).keyup(function() {
    $(this).test();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").test();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="456">
```

Comment: its unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Why not just put the keyup listener on the element itself?

Comment: @Kinglish Constantly prescribing events for each element is not very convenient. It is more convenient to initialize the element, and then everything is done in a function.